# No permitir puntos en expresión regular

Tags: javascript, regex

Que tal?

Implemente la siguiente expresión regular:
/^(\d*[.]\d*|)\d*$/

Lo que espero de la misma es que reconozca números enteros y decimales, pero al matchear ocurre lo siguiente:

- Cualquier digito no numérico - Incorrecto
- 12.1 - Incorrecto
- 12.12 - Incorrecto
- 1.2 - Incorrecto
- 0.8 - **Correcto** - Esto es lo que debería corregir
- 1562,30 - Correcto

Necesito que reconozca numero decimales con coma, no con punto.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si cambias el punto por la coma en tu expresión no es suficiente?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ya casi lo tenías, tan solo vendría cambiar el `.` por la `,` en tu expresión regular:

```js
function validarDecimal(numero) {
  regex = /^(\d*[,]\d*|)\d*$/gm;
  
  if (regex.test(numero)) {
    return 'Es decimal';
  } else {
    return 'No es decimal';
  }
}

console.log(validarDecimal('12.1'));
console.log(validarDecimal('12.12'));
console.log(validarDecimal('1.2'));
console.log(validarDecimal('0.8'));
console.log(validarDecimal('1562,30'));
```

Comment: Tu función recibe un argumento llamado `numero`, pero en la última llamada estás pasando 2 argumentos: `console.log(validarDecimal(1562,30));`. Por lo tanto sólo el primero es analizado. Por cierto, ¿sabes que las expresiones regulares se usan para analizar cadenas de texto y no valores numéricos?. Saludos

Comment: Sí, lo se muy bien, solo olvidé poner las comillas, gracias por la observación, saludos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias a todos por las respuestas! Gracias Cris, anduvo excelente.